# Applying two functions to the initial data frame with the %>%

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have this data frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

df <- data.table(Cnt=rep(c("REP","SWE","DK"), each=5), Scr=rnorm(15), w=1/15)
```

I want to calculate the weighted mean and variance for each group and obtain a new data.frame with a column for each statistic

```
    df %>%
    group_by(Cnt) %>%
    do(wtd.mean(Scr, w))
```

This will give me the weighted mean but any new function used after this line will operate on the output data frame which doesn't have the weights or the initial scores to estimate the variances. Thus

```
    df %>%
    group_by(Cnt) %>%
    do(wtd.mean(Scr, w)) %>%
    do(wtd.var(Scr,w))
```

will clearly not work.

Is there any way of applying consecutive function on the initial data frame?

Comment: df %>%
    group_by(Cnt) %>%
    summarize(wtd.mean(Scr, w),(wtd.var(Scr,w))

Comment: Thanks! That was it.